# Knockout.JS Mapping returning an empty array?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I've been scratching my head with this for the last day.. hope someone can shed some light. I have a simple javascript object -- data -- JSON.stringify(data) returns it like this;

```
{
    "dataList": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "0",
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "1",
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have a really simple knockout viewmodel;

```
var viewModel = {
            dataList: ko.observableArray([])
        };
```

I then do a simple knockout.JS mapping call as per the doc site;

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

I would expect my viewModel to now have a dataList member (it does) that is an array of 2 (it isn't!). Instead I get an empty array.. What am I missing in the mapping here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to define the properties on your viewModel object; the mapping plugin will create them for you. Just declare viewModel as such:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqaVT/

You only need to make the other call, `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel)`, when you need to *update* your viewModel with updated data from the server.

Comment: Interesting.. I noticed in your fiddle you did .dataList() -- why is this now a function? Is that correct for mapping?

Comment: Yes, the mapping plugin maps properties from the input into observables or observableArrays.

Comment: If you call with two parameters and the second one does not contain the '__ko_mapping__' property created by the plugin, I think it will treat it as the mapping and just return the view model.